# Unable to later review skipped Low Quality Posts reviews, which is normally allowed for other review queues

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, low-quality-posts

When reviewing Low Quality Posts, I accidentally pressed Skip instead of Recommend Deletion. So when I noticed my mistake, I went back by pressing the browser's "go back" button. The problem is that now the item is not reviewable:

[image]

After some testing, I've figured out that it seems to happen every time I press Skip and then visit the review item again, either by pressing the browser's back button, following a link from my review history, or visiting that URL in any other way. However, refreshing the page or even closing the tab and then copy-pasting the URL into a new tab works just fine, so it seems to only happen after having pressed the Skip button.

Here are two examples where it happened:

- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15276440
- https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/15276442

This happens **only** with the Low Quality Posts queue; in other review queues, I *can still* review an item by navigating back to it after skipping it initially.

Can this bug please be fixed?

Comment: [Cross-site dupe](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/340746/why-does-lqp-mark-reviews-not-reviewable-immediately-after-i-skip-without-any)

Comment: This bug is really annoying, since it encourages us to avoid skipping any review we think we might ever want to complete. I would be surprised if this weren't leading to numerous bad reviews. Whether unintentional or by design, the inability to return to a LQP review item we've skipped encourages us to behave irresponsibly while reviewing.

Comment: I've found a way to work around this. Go to the review that you skipped, right click on the Next button, and select Inspect. Then the browser's developer tools will appear. In the developer tools, you will find somewhere where it says `<input type="button" value="Next" title="review next item" data-result-type="254">`. Change `254` to `7` for Looks OK, `5` for Edit and `9` for Recommend Deletion. I did that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/18785793) and it worked, but it would still be nice if this bug could be fixed.

Comment: Using the back button mess up JavaScript code that was executed before pressing it. Since the review use lots of JS, it's expected to break.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It's not only the back button that does that. It also does that if you skip and then go into your review history, check the "show skipped reviews" checkbox, and then follow a link from there. It has nothing to do with the back button.

Comment: I noticed that [Low Quality Posts reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355324/2020-10-13-3rd-time-random-pages-across-se-feel-dead-due-to-se-websocket-m#comment1187360_355324) have a different behavior than the other queues; once you've had a look and closed the tab / gone elsewhere there's 'no going back' (without some persistent messing around). The other three queues don't lock you out like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

Each queue has a general filter to exclude non-skip reviewed tasks when picking new ones, but a handful of queues have cross-validation on post ID.  The apparent thought is that we don't want the reviewer handling the same post in multiple queues.  (For example, the same post could end up in First Posts and Late Answers.) Unfortunately, this additional exclusion logic treated skipped tasks as reviews and prevented them from being returned to.

Comment: Brian, at MSO they complain [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409440/839601) about strange behavior of skipped reviews in LQ queue, could this be a side effect of recent change?

Comment: Still broken as of 7/29/2021 15:36 Zulu.  It's impossible to skip a review item.

Comment: above issue looks like also reported over here at MSE: [Skipped Review Tasks Showing Again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/368005/165773)

Answer (score 6):

We're taking a look at this as part of ongoing work on the review queues. So far, it is unclear whether this behavior is intentional or an oversight. I'm hoping we'll be able to dig up some history internally, but unless we come up with something absolutely showstopping, I expect we'll be fixing this.

We'll post an update here once we have a decision either way.